# How do I automatically change my mac address in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, boot

Im running ubuntu 12.10, using wicd to connect to the wlan.
I would like my wlan0 mac address changed before it sends anything.  I'm willing to use a script if needed.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you already are familiar with `macchanger` since you allude to it in your question, so the steps would be to create an [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) script to [change our MAC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54798/how-to-change-wlan0-mac-adress) with macchanger, then set it run before networking (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146690/how-to-start-a-task-before-networking)).